# server socket javascript and client android . Its possible?

Tags: javascript, android

. Its possible to develop a server socket on javascript and client android.
If its possible how can i send message from socket server made in java script to client made in android.. help me plsss

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, using node.js...you can create websocket server. :-) In android devices, I only tested it in firefox mobile browser...maybe you can achieve your goal if you will use phonegap.